# Singleton with Generics Argument

Tags: java, generics, singleton

How can I create my instance?

I always get compilation errors.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type COMPONENT ComponentManager.java

```
package component;

public class ComponentManager<COMPONENT extends Component> {

private static ComponentManager<COMPONENT> instance = new ComponentManager<COMPONENT >();

private ComponentManager() {

}

public static ComponentManager<?> getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

}
```

Comment: If you get compilation errors and want our help, please consider posting the error messages in their entirety.

Comment: You appear to be possibly missing import statements for one, unless you have your own Component class.

Comment: I take from your code that you want N singletons, each for a subclass of `Component`? If that is the case it won't work due to **type erasure**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong on the declaration and instantiation. Create 'instance' like this:

```
private static ComponentManager<? extends Component> instance = new ComponentManager< >();
```

Comment: It should and does work for me, at least for compilation. Java 7 added limited type inference capabilities.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Comment: @daveed007. Ah! sorry. It was fault on my side. It compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `new ComponentManager()` line inside the `getInstance()` method call the constructor if `instance` is null, otherwise return `instance`.

```
public class ComponentManager {

    private static ComponentManager instance;

    private ComponentManager() {

    }

    public static ComponentManager getInstance() {
        if (instance  != null) {

        } else {
            instance = new ComponentManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: I wanna do my getInstance() without if conditional.